# Flask unable to receive chunked data

Tags: python-2.7, flask

I am kinda newby in python thus the question.

I am trying to create a simple http web server that can receive chunked data from a post request. 
I have realized later that once a request sends a headers with chunked data, the Content-length headers will be set to zero, thus reading the sent data with 'request.get_data()' will fail.

Is there another way of reading the chunked data?
The request I receive does give me the data length in the 'X-Data-Length' headers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This might be a good question. Can you provide what you've tried so far in your question? Here are some helpful sites for you to formulate a question and get a better chance of high quality answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Did you write both of the js upload file code and the flask in backend to handle upload request? If not then you will need some help with js to upload it.

One way to achieve chucked data upload is:

2. Chucked that file in the frontend with js. Give it some headers in the request for the total size, number of the chunk, chunk size... and send each chuck in a separate POST request (You can use dropzone.js for example, they will do the job for you, just need to config the params)
3. In the backend, create an upload API which will read the request headers and merge the file chunks back together

Comment: I write the server myself, not the request. Also, the request does give me the total data length.

Comment: Which version of wsgi you are using? I see in git issue of flask and found this problem in there. They have fixed it in the newer version [link](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/2229)

Comment: How can I check the version?

Comment: you can use `pip freeze || grep Werkzeug`

Comment: Flask == 0.10.1, Werkzeug == 0.10.4